# check if input is float in swift

Tags: swift, textfield

Is there an easy way to check if the textfield input is integer or decimal number? For integer only it's easy:

```
func isNumber(text:String)->Bool
{
    if let intVal = text.toInt()
        {return true}
    else
        {return false}
}
```

However whenever I have a decimal number I do not know how to verify.
For example:

```
var str:String="11.5"
if(isNumber(str))
    {println("yes")}
else
    {println("no")}
    //prints "no"
```

Comment: By the way... println() was changed to print(). You may want to update and get acclimated to Swift 2 as soon as possible -- there were a bunch of changes to string-related functions, among other aspects.

Answer (score 3):

Try code below:

```
var str = "11.5"
if let mFloat = Float(str) {
    print("Your string is float.")
}else {
    print("else")
}

if let mInt = Int(str) {
    print("Your string is integer.")
}else {
    print("Your string is not integer")
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Eric D. I shown two case for check a string is float or integer. Your case is work for float and integer. It's fine for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Pretty easy though

```
var str = "87.8"
var numberOfDots=0
var hasLetterOrSymbol=false

var char:Character="a"

for char in str
{


if(char == ".")
    {numberOfDots++}
if((char > "9") || (char < "0")) && (char != ".")
    {
        hasLetterOrSymbol=true
    }


  }

 if(numberOfDots>1) || (hasLetterOrSymbol==true)
    {
        println("wrong input. Please enter an integer or decimal number")
    }
else
    {
        var floatNumber = (str as NSString).floatValue
        println(floatNumber)
    }
```